# Proving that 3 regular NFA equivalent to NFA

Tags: computer-science, automata

> Let 3 regular NFA be an NFA automata, which satisfies the following: $$\forall q\in Q,\forall\sigma\in \Sigma:|\delta(q,\sigma)|=3$$
> Prove that the 3 regular NFA model is equivalent to NFA.

---

$Proof.$ we shall prove that the given 3 regular NFA model is equivalent to DFA model.

$First\ Direction.$ for the first direction, we can turn any DFA automata to 3 regular NFA automata which gets the same language, doing the following:$$\text{if}\ \delta_D(q,a)=p \  \ \text{then: } \ \delta_{N_3}(q,a)=\{p,q_{pit_1},q_{pit_2}\}$$

$Second\ Direction.$ for the second direction, we can turn any NFA automata to DFA automata which gets the same language, doing the following:

Let $N$ be 3 regular NFA, while $Q_{N_3}$ is the states' set, $\Sigma$ is the alphabet, starting state $q_0$, a set of accepted states $F_{N_3}$, and the transition function $\delta_{N_3}$. We define the following DFA:

- The set of states is the set of all subsets of length 3 belongs to $Q_{N_3}$, which means that: $Q_{D} =\left\{X\in \mathcal{P}( Q_{N_{3}})\Bigl| |X|=3\right\}$.
- An alphabet $\Sigma$.
- a starting state ${q_0}$
- An accepted states' set $F_D$: contains any subset of $Q_{N_3}$ in length 3, which contains an element from $F_{N_3}$.
- A transition function $\delta_D:$ such that $\delta_D({q_1,\dots, q_k},a)$ is the set generated by the union of each $i=1,\dots ,k$ of $\delta_{N_3}(q_i,a)$

Now, we know already that the DFA model is equivalent to the NFA model, and therefore, we get that the 3 regular NFA model is equivalent to the NFA model. $Q.E.D$

---

I am not sure whether it's correct or not because it is a bit complex. I will be glad to see what you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks good to me! I particularly like your idea to use DFAs instead of NFAs directly, as it's *easy* to add transitions but potentially *hard* to remove transitions (which would be necessary for an NFA with some large number of out transitions). Here are a few pointers, though, to make your life a bit easier. I'll write $3$-NFA instead of $3$-regular NFA throughout, because life is short.

First, you should be a bit more clear in your DFA $\implies$ $3$-NFA direction. What are $q_{\text{pit}_1}$ and $q_{\text{pit}_2}$? You should be a bit more explicit as to their intended behavior (even though it's obvious from the names). Depending on how much of a stickler your grader is, this could matter. Similarly, it's worth taking one (1) sentence to show that your modified DFA really is a $3$-NFA. Obviously it *is*, but again, a mean grader could take off points for you not including a proof.

Second, there's no need to duplicate work. In showing that $3$-NFAs can be turned into equivalent DFAs, you're basically redoing the argument that a *general* NFA can be converted into a DFA. Of course, you've almost certainly seen this argument before, which lets you sidestep this argument entirely! Every $3$-NFA is, in particular, an NFA. So if you know that NFAs can be converted into DFAs, then you *also* know $3$-NFAs can be! Because a $3$-NFA is a special case of an NFA! This means you can say something like "Since any NFA has an equivalent DFA, and every $3$-NFA is an NFA, we get the $3$-NFA $\implies$ DFA direction as a corollary of an earlier result".

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much! I like what you wrote and especially how you wrote it. 
In addition, in the second direction, can I also define $Q_{D} =\left\{X\in \mathcal{P}( Q_{N_{3}})\Bigl| |X| \geq 3\right\}$ instead?

Comment: That probably works, but why think? Just add a state for _every_ possible subset. If you end up with some extra states, who cares. This is an existence proof, so there's no need to split hairs about efficiency

Comment: Right, but in $F_D$ I still have to take all subsets of length 3, which contains an element from $F_{N_3}$. Right? because if I just take all subsets from $F_{N_3}$ then it doesn't work right?